# Why isn't the default template used?

Tags: 7, rules, mimemail

I set Mime Mail as the sitewide default mailing system and overrode `mimemail-message.tpl.php`. My custom template is used correctly for e-mails like account activation, but when I send an HTML e-mail with Rules, the template isn't loaded: I simply get an unstyled HTML text.

Did I forget something (e.g. a configuration for Rules)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your administration theme the active theme when the Rule fires? [This documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/958146) about using a custom mail template with Mime Mail might be referencing the issue:

> If you use sub-themes or multiple themes, especially if you use a different administration theme than your default theme, you might end up with a different theme to what you expect.

In the Mail System module configuration settings (admin/config/system/mailsystem), try changing the **Theme to render the emails** from Current to the Default theme or to the theme where your overridden `mimemail-message.tpl.php` lives.

[image: Theme to render emails dropdown]

Comment: Of course! Subtle difference between *Current* and *Default*...